# Как сделать прокрутку на колёсико в 100vh?

Tags: javascript

Весь сайт сделан блоками по 100vh, хочется, чтобы при скролле был плавный переход от секции к секции, как это можно реализовать на чистом js или jQ?

Comment: Слушаете событие `mousewheel`/`wheel `, отменяете его обычное действие (`preventDefault()`), определяете направление, так называемую "дельту" (может понадобиться [кроссбраузерный способ](https://learn.javascript.ru/mousewheel#tippglwbwk)) и прокручиваете страницу любым понравившимся вам способом, например, [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
let currIndex = 0;

const onScroll = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const direction = e.deltaY > 0 ? 1 : -1;
  
  currIndex = Math.max(0, Math.min(currIndex + direction, blocks.length));
  
  blocks[currIndex].scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
  })
}

document.addEventListener('wheel', onScroll)
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  height: 100vh;
}

.block:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}
.block:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
.block:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
.block:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

1. Находим все блоки
2. Вешаем слушателя `'wheel'`
3. Отменяем стандарнтое поведение
4. Определяем направление
5. Плавно перемщаемся к элементу